waitForResponse - wait for all 3 (identical-url) responses
In Playwright (TS) I want to wait for the end of all 3 responses that share the same url and payload.
Only when all 3 responses are done, I can move further with the test.
I have tried this, but it always wait for only first response.
await Promise.all([
    page.waitForResponse(resp => resp.url().includes('/variations')),
    page.waitForResponse(resp => resp.url().includes('/variations')),
    page.waitForResponse(resp => resp.url().includes('/variations')),
]);


So there is an one response containing 3 keywords which you need to verify?

There are 3 responses with the same keyword (they have the same URL), but waitForResponse allows me to wait just for the one of them, when I need all 3 to end.

They are all the same event, of course it doesn't work, instead of waiting for three events you are waiting for the same event three times.
You need to create a special handling for this case if you don't want to await three times in a row separately, for example:
async function waitForMultipleResponses(page, urlPart, count) {
    let responseCount = 0;

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const responseHandler = (response) => {
            if (response.url().includes(urlPart)) {
                responseCount++;
                if (responseCount === count) {
                    page.off("response", responseHandler);
                    resolve();
                }
            }
        };

        page.on("response", responseHandler);
    });
}

await waitForMultipleResponses(page, '/variations', 3);

This answer has a better implementation.

Don't forget to remove the event listener when finished. page.off("response", handleFn), otherwise this leaks memory. Better yet, use waitForResponse which is already async.

I'll fix it when in front of computer. I actually don't really know about playright, it was just simple understanding of promise's and event's, the code suggest is general handling of such case, thats why i wrote "something like", i don't want people to think this is the exact solution. But ill fix it for the copy paster that we all are.

Directed to your response

This answer is technically correct, but has a memory leak, uses an unnecessary promisification and doesn't let you run any assertions on the responses.
waitForResponsse is already async, so just use that, but don't resolve (i.e. return true) just because the URL matches--resolve when your matched URL count matches the expected count.
Here's as complete, verifiable, minimal example you can adapt to your use case:
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.46.1

const html = `<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<script>
setTimeout(() => fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"), 1000);
setTimeout(() => fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"), 2000);
setTimeout(() => fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"), 4000);
</script></body>/html>`;

const waitForAllResponses = (page, urlPart, responsesExpected) => {
  let responses = 0;
  return page.waitForResponse(resp => {
    if (resp.url().includes(urlPart) && ++responses >= responsesExpected) {
      return true;
    }
  });
};

test("Waits for 3 responses from /users", async ({page}) => {
  const allUsersResponsesArrived = waitForAllResponses(page, urlPart, 3);
  await page.setContent(html);
  await allUsersResponsesArrived;
  expect("test whatever you want here").toBeTruthy();
});

Output (the 4 second test duration proves that we're truly waiting for all 3 responses):
$ npx playwright test pw.test.js

Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✓  1 pw.test.js:19:1 › Waits for 3 responses from /users (4.1s)

  1 passed (4.7s)

If you need to use the responses in subsequent assertions, you can store them in an array:
const waitForAllResponses = async ({
  page,
  urlPart,
  responsesExpected,
}) => {
  const responses = [];
  await page.waitForResponse(response => {
    if (response.url().includes(urlPart)) {
      responses.push(response);
      return responses.length === responsesExpected;
    }
  });
  return responses;
};

test("Waits for 3 responses from /users", async ({page}) => {
  const allUsersResponsesArrived = waitForAllResponses({
    page,
    urlPart: "/users",
    responsesExpected: 3,
  });
  await page.setContent(html);
  const responses = await allUsersResponsesArrived;

  // these are contrived assertions since you know they must be true,
  // but you may want to assert more interesting things IRL
  expect(responses).toHaveLength(3);
  expect(responses[0].url()).toContain("/users");
  expect(responses[1].url()).toContain("/users");
  expect(responses[2].url()).toContain("/users");
});

urlPart makes the function fairly inflexible, so if you want to generalize this, allow the user to provide an arbitrary predicate function:
const waitForAllResponses = async ({
  page,
  predicate,
  responsesExpected,
}) => {
  const responses = [];
  await page.waitForResponse(response => {
    if (predicate(response)) {
      responses.push(response);
      return responses.length === responsesExpected;
    }
  });
  return responses;
};

test("Waits for 3 responses from /users", async ({page}) => {
  const allUsersResponsesArrived = waitForAllResponses({
    page,
    predicate: res => res.url().includes("/users"),
    responsesExpected: 3,
  });
  await page.setContent(html);
  const responses = await allUsersResponsesArrived;
  expect(responses).toHaveLength(3);
});

